# How to send NextAuth cookie to different domain back end?

Tags: flask, cookies, backend, token

I'm making an Next app which is hosted on Vercel, it uses serverless api routes (app folder) for authentication using NextAuth. When a user signs in, NextAuth provides a token stored in a session cookie, the token stores the user_id, user_name, email.

I also have another, separate, heroku backend, all in python, that handles doing database manipulations with pandas.

In order to update my user data for the correct user, i'm wanting to send the NextAuth session cookie to my python back end where it is decoded/decrypted in order to retrieve the user_id, this tells my python back end for which user i need to update the database.

But i can't get the cookie to be sent through, even though i'm using "withCredentials: true" in my axios.post() function because the front end and python back end are on different domains, all settings i tried didn't work, the request goes through but without the cookie.

I could decode the token and just send the user_id along with the request to the python back end so that it know which user to update, but then my user_id would be exposed to the front end user, wouldn't that be bad ? how could i validate that the user is real if anyone can just send a request to my back end route with a custom user_id ?

What's the proper way of handling this ? Sorry for all the questions, i'm a bit confused by all this.

I tried this in my NextAuth options:

```
  cookies: {
    sessionToken: {
      name: `__Secure-next-auth.session-token`,
      options: {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'none',  // Explicitly allow cross-site cookie
        path: '/',
        secure: true
      }
    },
```

Request is OK but sent without the cookie, my front end call to the python back end:

```
const response = await axios.post(`${serverURL}/api/analyze-my-files`, {
        query: userQuery,
        db: fileContent,
      }, {
        timeout: 30000,
        withCredentials: true,
      });
```

My headers are exposed and i allow all origins on my back end so i know it's not a CORS issue.